# Trigonometry and vectors

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> Suppose vector $\vec u= \langle -3, -3\rangle$ and vector $\vec v=
> > \langle 3,-15\rangle$ are two vectors that form the sides of a
>   parallelogram. Then the lengths of the two diagonals of the
>   parallelogram are…

I have gotten only half the answer right so far. I got 18 for one. Please help. I have attempted this problem 60 times according to my online math homework. If someone could explain to me how to do a problem like this I would be so grateful!!

Comment: distance formula on $(-3,-3)$ and $(3,-15)$ for the shorter diagonal

Comment: The vertices of the paralellogram are $(0, 0), u, v$, and $u + v$. Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: There’s no trigonometry required to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem correctly, these two vectors will outline two of the four sides of something that looks like a slanted rectangle.  Therefore, the length of the diagonal will be the segment that connects the two endpoints. You can add the two vectors together and then calculate the length of the resultant, or you can use the distance formula on the endpoints of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$.

[image: map]

In this image, $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are shown on the Cartesian plane and labeled in color. The dashed lines represent the would-be sides of the parallelogram. The green line segment shows the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Find $u+v$ and $u-v$.

$u = <-3,-3>$

$v = <3,-15>$

$u+v = <0,-18>$

$u-v = <-6,12>$

Now find magnitudes of $u+v$ and $u-v$.

That is $18$ and $36\sqrt5$